# Thunks api testing error when I pass user data

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

When I am passing user session for `dataAPI(userSession)` getting an error. If I am not passing any user parameters to the API then it will work, but I need to pass the bearer token dynamically to the API. How can I fix it?

**Test code:**

```
    it("should call get the data centers' API correctly and get correct values", async () => {
      const getSpy = jest.spyOn(dataAPI(userSession), "get").mockResolvedValueOnce({
      data: dataCenters,
    });

    await mockedStore.dispatch(getDataCenters());
    expect(getSpy).toBeCalled();
    expect(getSpy).toBeCalledWith(`DataCenters/GetDataCenters`);
    const state = mockedStore.getState();
    expect(state.dataCenter.dataCenters).toEqual(dataCenters);
  });

export const userSession = {
  sessionId: "123RalIh1QCvPYtNi5hs",
  bearerToken: "abcdKQmBWheOqLdxa4H50HiPii6kcwK64"
}
```

**Thunks API code:**

```
export const getDataCenters = createAsyncThunk(
  "data-centers/getDataCenters",
  async (requestData, { getState, dispatch }) => {
    try {
      dispatch(setLoading(true));
      const user = JSON.parse(String(sessionStorage.getItem("user")));
      const result = await dataAPI(user).get(`DataCenters/GetDataCenters`);
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
      return result.data;
    } catch (error: any) {
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
      throw error;
    }
  }
);

export const dataAPI = (user: any) => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: apiUrl,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${user.bearerToken}`
    },
  });
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Show the code of the `dataAPI` function  and how did you import it?

Comment: @LinDu code updated for dataAPI

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77540776/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77540776/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that can go wrong on this line right here:

```
const user = JSON.parse(String(sessionStorage.getItem("user")));
```

- What happens if sessionStorage is unavailable?
- What happens if the value is not proper JSON and cannot be parsed as such?
- What happens if the value is null?

You have a try/catch that should be throwing a specific error that would be more help to you than the message in your test. Is there an exception thrown that we could see?

I would make sure that the above line specifically is returning an object that aligns with your expectation in the userSession object and I would validate that the bearer token used can be decoded correctly.